# how to create customer and charge subscription at same time?

Tags: php, stripe-payments, checkout, stripe.js

I'm using stripe and had all my subscriptions working properly before. 
Just recently I am trying to move the same code to a different stripe account and I am receiving errors when trying to charge a subscription.

```
<?php 


require_once('../stripe-php-master/init.php');


// (switch to the live key later)
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey("sk_test_hlQNSE1fy1cGmsqDSbR9LfDF");

try
{
  $customer = \Stripe\Customer::create(array(
    'email' => $_POST['stripeEmail'],
    'source'  => $_POST['stripeToken'],
    'plan' => 'basic_annually'
  ));

  header('Location: ../../subscription-success.html');
  exit;
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
  header('Location:oops.html');
  error_log("unable to sign up customer:" . $_POST['stripeEmail'].
    ", error:" . $e->getMessage());
}
```

this is returning the following error

```
unable to sign up customer: 'test@example.com', error:No such plan: basic_monthly; one exists with a name of basic_monthly, but its ID is 504102373103330.
```

Comment: as you said you are trying to use same code for different Stripe Account. does that Stripe account have plan with `ID` `basic_annually` defined??

Comment: And yes if `ID` is `504102373103330` you need to pass that in `plan`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Plan objects](https://stripe.com/docs/api#plan_object) have both an [`id`](https://stripe.com/docs/api#plan_object-id) and a [`name`](https://stripe.com/docs/api#plan_object-name) attribute. `id` is the plan's unique identifier while `name` is its display name.

When [creating a customer](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_customer) or [a subscription](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_subscription), the value of the [`plan`](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_subscription-items-plan) parameter must be set to a valid plan ID, not to a plan's name.

In your case, the error message explicitly tells you that there is plan with `"basic_monthly"` as its `name`, but the plan's `id` is `504102373103330`, so that's the value you'd need to pass in the `plan` parameter to create a subscription to that plan.

Answer (score -2):

you must change secret and test api keys